# Extract matrices from hierarchical file structure

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, json, file-system

I have a set of JSON files stored in a folder;
the folder structure is as follows:

```
Main_folder
----F1
-----I1
------X.json
-----I2
-------X.json
.
.
.
.
.
.
```

In all, the main folder contains 36 subfolders which in turn contain 10 subfolders each having a JSON file.

The JSON file is a dictionary of a lists
X={'a':[contains 73 items each of which is a dictionary that represents a 2x3 matrix],'b':[contains 73 items each of which is a dictionary]}

I want to read these JSON files, get the 2x3 matrices and store them in `.npy` files.

My current code does that but it ends up saving the same npy file multiple times in the folders.
For example, `X_0.npy` should be stored once in `Main_folder/F1/I1`, but that same file is being saved in other folders also.

```
import os, json,codecs
import numpy as np
from pathlib import Path

def read_pose_from_json(json_file):
    #read json file and obtain 73x6 pose array
    with open(json_file) as f1:
        json1_str=f1.read()
        json1_data=json.loads(json1_str)
    data=json1_data.copy()
    l1=data['world_coordinate']
    pose_list=[]
    for i in range(len(l1)):
        X=list(l1[i].values())[0]
        X=np.array(X).ravel()
        pose_list.append(X)
    return np.array(pose_list)

path_to_json='blender_files/'
paths=[]
paths1=[]

#For all json files ,read them obtain pose array(73x6) and store it  in a npy file so that it can
#later be accesed
for (dirpath,dirnames,filenames) in os.walk(path_to_json):
    paths+=[os.path.join(dirpath,file) for file in filenames if  file.startswith('bones_') and file.endswith('.json')]
    for i in range(len(paths)):
        pose_array=read_pose_from_json(paths[i])
        new_pose_file=Path(paths[i]).stem+".npy"
        new_pose_file=os.path.join(dirpath,new_pose_file)
        with open(new_pose_file,'wb') as f:
            np.save(f,pose_array)
```

What steps can I take to optimize this code, and ensure that redundant copies of the same file are not created?

I have enclosed a screenshot which shows what the code is currently doing:
[image: redudant npy files being saved]

In this image inside `Model23/image7` there are multiple npy files being saved.

I was able to resolve the issue,I moved the loop

```
for i in range(len(pathfiles)
```

outside the  loop that recursively looks in all folders and sub-folders.
so for now the correct code is

```
use os.walk() to list all json files and store them in list path
```

```
then iterate through paths list and obtain matrices and save them
```

If anyone else can suggest a better solution,that would be appreciated.

Comment: Are your data uniformly non-jagged (as in, 36 x 9 x 73 x 2 x 3)? If so, I'll recommend that this go to one `npz` and not multiple.

Comment: Not enough for a full review, but you can simplify matching the files using `pathlib`: `files = Path('blender_files').glob('*/*/bones_*.json')`

Comment: You say _9 subfolders each having a JSON file_ but your `bones_20` example has 10 items?

Comment: sorry about that,yes each subfolder has 10 images going from 0-9

Comment: Reinderien no data is not non jagged all matrices are of dimension 3x2.You can look at openpose or SMPL to get a sense of the data with which i am working.

Comment: For the purposes of code review we don't support references to external sites (or even links to external site) - instead you'll need to paste an actual sample in your question.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review@SE. As presented, you process "the files at the beginning of `paths`" over and again. Correcting that is *debugging*. (Hint: What if you ditch `paths`?)

Answer (score 2):

If this is true:

> the main folder contains 36 subfolders which in turn contain 10 subfolders

and we assume your `F1` / `I1` naming scheme is accurate and the contradictory `Model` / `image` naming scheme is not, then my recommendation is:

- Don't make separate output files; make one six-dimensional array output to one file. The result turns out to be about 12MB based on test data that have the same shape as yours.
- Don't `ravel`; preserve the original dimensions
- Don't `f1.read()` and pass that to `json.loads`; just use `json.load`
- Don't `copy()`
- Don't cast `values()` to a `list` and then index it. If you know the key, use the key. If you (strangely) don't know the key, then use `next(iter())`.
- Don't make and dynamically grow a `pose_list`. Instead, pre-allocate a Numpy array and assign to that using slices.
- `paths1` is unused; delete it
- Move your code out of the global namespace
- Don't `os.walk` and don't `glob`; if you know the indices, just use them directly to construct paths
- Use PEP484 type hints

### Suggested

```
import json
from random import random

import numpy as np
from pathlib import Path


def read_pose_from_json(json_file: Path) -> np.ndarray:
    """read json file and obtain 73x2x3 pose array"""

    with json_file.open() as f:
        data = json.load(f)['world_coordinate']

    poses = np.empty((len(data), 2, 3))

    for i, entry in enumerate(data):
        poses[i, :, :] = next(iter(entry.values()))

    return poses


def main() -> None:
    n_f = 36
    n_i = 10
    n_images = 10
    all_poses = np.empty((
        n_f, n_i, n_images, 73, 2, 3,
    ))

    for f_index in range(n_f):
        for i_index in range(n_i):
            subdir = Path(f'blender_files/F{f_index+1}/I{i_index+1}')
            for image_index in range(n_images):
                path = subdir / f'bones_{image_index}.json'
                all_poses[
                    f_index, i_index, image_index, :, :, :,
                ] = read_pose_from_json(path)

    np.save('all_poses', all_poses)


def make_testing_dir() -> None:
    for f_index in range(1, 37):
        for i_index in range(1, 11):
            subdir = Path(f'blender_files/F{f_index}/I{i_index}')
            subdir.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

            for image_index in range(10):
                data = {
                    'world_coordinate': [  # l1
                        {  # l1[i]
                            'spooky_unknown_key': [  # l1[i].values()[0]
                                [random() for x in range(3)]
                                for y in range(2)
                            ],
                            'zzz-ignored-key': None,  # ...
                        }
                        for pose_index in range(73)
                    ]
                }

                filename = subdir / f'bones_{image_index}.json'
                with filename.open('w') as f:
                    json.dump(data, f)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # make_testing_dir()
    main()
```

Comment: thanks,for the suggestions I will use them in my future codes.